# jQuery / HTML scrolling behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

So I have a page that is split into 2 columns. The left column there are expandable forms that are quite long to ask the user optional product preferences. On the right side of the page there is a much shorter, 'contact details' form. The contact details form is mandatory.

The behaviour idea is that as the user scrolls down to complete the left column optional forms, the page will only scroll the left column - the contact details forms displayed in the right column stays in place to avoid a big gaping white space where the right column is empty. I'm having trouble implementing this and I haven't found a solution yet or any examples of pages with this split column behaviour online.

Any advice / suggestions / examples online? Thanks!

Comment: This question is almost word-for-word, the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623960 .  Is this homework?

Comment: The user duplicated this question, **again**, with one added detail.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628984/fixing-scrolling-behaviour-with-jquery .

Answer (score 0):

User `overflow:scroll` for the left column.